# Is there a optimised function in openCV to apply joint bilateral filtering using two guidance image?

Tags: opencv, filter

Is there an optimized function in OpenCV to implement joint bilateral filtering using two guidance image? 
The current implementation is designed to work including, a guidance image and an input image

Equation:

[image]

Opencv Function call

```
cv::ximgproc::jointBilateralFilter(guidanceImage, input, output,d, sigmaColor, sigma space);
```

Currently, I implement it using two calls to joint bilateral filter

[image: enter image d> escription here]

```
cv::ximgproc::jointBilateralFilter(guidanceImage1, input, output1,d, sigmaColor, sigma space);
cv::ximgproc::jointBilateralFilter(guidanceImage2, output1, output2,d, sigmaColor, sigma space);
```

This is not an optimized application and it slows down the update rate. Please, suggest a better solution.

https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/8290/82900E/Efficient-spatio-temporal-hole-filling-strategy-for-Kinect-depth-maps/10.1117/12.911909.short?SSO=1

Comment: Where did you get these equations?

Comment: I referred to a paper where joint bilateral filtering using two guidance image was proposed. I wrote these equations in a latex editor taking inspiration from that paper and generated a gif file to upload here.